# Unable to retrieve the access token to publish on a page

Tags: php, facebook

When I try to regenerate an access token with publish_pages rights, I get the error.

Invalid Scopes: manage_pages. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

I have big problems with access tokens for 1 week, and therefore impossible to post on the Fb page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug right now, showing several permissions as invalid: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/600976503711113/

The only thing you can do is subscribe to the bug, and add your informaion in comments if you want to.